# Linkedin API for get User Info in PHP Not working

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Here is my Code for get Access token and get profile data.

```
            $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
            h1('Access token');
            pp($accessToken); // print the access token content
            h1('Profile');
            
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            // perform api call to get profile information
            $profile = $client->get(        
                'userinfo',                       
                ['fields' => 'sub,name']
            );
```

When i click on login URL it shows like this.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJWlS.png)

Here is the scope i am using for the login URL.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dOG3.png)

Here is the screenshot of the approved app from LinkedIn developer dashboard.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXMgt.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sstu7.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask].